# Calculate total observation days in R (lubridate + dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am working with a dataset where each row contains a separate observation of an individual (ID). I would like R to look for the first and last observation dates and calculate the total number of "activity days", putting these values in a new column. When I run the code below, I get one column with the same number for every entry — the total number of days between the earliest and latest days of the entire data set, not per individual.

I’m using dplyr and lubridate. I used this page ([difference between the first date and last date within same individual in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673673/difference-between-the-first-date-and-last-date-within-same-individual-in-r)) for code assistance, but it isn't working for me.

Can anyone help me figure out where I’m going wrong?

```
data$date <- mdy(data$date)

data <- data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(total.activity.days = max((date)) - min((date)))

   cage   date              ID   total.activity.days
1   1     2018-04-30        40   54
2   1     2018-04-30        76   54 
3   1     2018-05-02        40   54 
4   1     2018-05-02        76   54
5   1     2018-05-04        40   54
6   1     2018-05-04        76   54
7   1     2018-04-28        59   54
8   1     2018-04-29        59   54
```

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice that. I ran the code again with that item fixed, but the same problem persists. The number in the new column is the same for every row.

Comment: No need for `data$date <- mdy(data$date)` if you are using `ymd` during your calculations. Also, why using `mdy` when year is first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is needed is:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(total.activity.days = max(date) - min(date) )
```

Which gives:

```
cage    date          ID total.activity.days
  <int> <date>     <int> <time>             
1     1 2018-04-30    40 4                  
2     1 2018-04-30    76 4                  
3     1 2018-05-02    40 4                  
4     1 2018-05-02    76 4                  
5     1 2018-05-04    40 4                  
6     1 2018-05-04    76 4                  
7     1 2018-04-28    59 1                  
8     1 2018-04-29    59 1
```

Comment: This should work! But for some reason, on my computer, I get "6" for every row in the "total.activity.days" column.

Comment: what does str(data) produce?

Comment: I just reinstalled every package and re-loaded the data again, and suddenly it's working! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
data_new <- data %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(MaxDate = max(date),
              MinDate = min(date)) %>% 
    mutate(total.activity.days = MaxDate - MinDate) %>% 
    select(ID, total.activity.days)
```